# A question on equation with logarithm involving different bases

Tags: logarithms

Find the value of $x$ from the equation:$$\log_{(2x+5)}{(10x^2+29x+10)}=5-\log_{(5x+2)}{(4x^2+20x+25)}$$

This question seems bit tricky (especially because the bases of the log are different) and on first instance leaves clueless on how to proceed. How to find value of $x$ from this equation.

Comment: Just from glancing at the problem, I might try to use the change of base formula.  Not sure if that will take you anywhere relevant though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log _{ (2x+5) }{ (10x^{ 2 }+29x+10) } +\log _{ (5x+2) }{ (4x^{ 2 }+20x+25) } =5\\ \log _{ \left( 2x+5 \right)  }{ \left( 2x+5 \right) \left( 5x+2 \right)  } +\log _{ \left( 5x+2 \right)  }{ { \left( 2x+5 \right)  }^{ 2 } } =5\\ \log _{ \left( 2x+5 \right)  }{ \left( 2x+5 \right) +\log _{ \left( 2x+5 \right)  }{ \left( 5x+2 \right)  } +2\log _{ \left( 5x+2 \right)  }{ \left( 2x+5 \right)  } =5 } \\ 1+\log _{ \left( 2x+5 \right)  }{ \left( 5x+2 \right)  } +2\log _{ \left( 5x+2 \right)  }{ \left( 2x+5 \right)  } =5\\ \log _{ \left( 2x+5 \right)  }{ \left( 5x+2 \right)  } +2\log _{ \left( 5x+2 \right)  }{ \left( 2x+5 \right)  } =4$$
now solve quadratic equation and set$$\log _{ \left( 2x+5 \right)  }{ \left( 5x+2 \right)  } =y\\ y+\frac { 2 }{ y } =4$$

Comment: sounds good. this looks a simple quadratic equation now

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the following:

$x = -5/2$

Here's how to derive it:

Use the change of base formula to make everything in terms of $\log_{5 x + 2}$:

${ \log_{5x+2} (10 x^2 + 29 x + 10) \over \log_{5x+2}(2 x + 5)} = 5 - \log_{5 x+2} (4 x^2 + 20 x + 25)$

and noting $5 = \log_{5 x +2} (5 x +2)^5$,

then

$(10 x^2 + 29 x + 10) = (2 x+5)((5x+2)^5-(4 x^2 + 20 x + 25))$

Which gives the solution quoted above.

Comment: sweet and concise solution!

Answer (score 1):

you can write $$\frac{\ln(10x^2+20x+10)}{\ln(2x+5)}=5-\frac{\ln(4x^2+20x+25)}{\ln(5x+2)}$$
note that $$10x^2+20x+10=10(x+1)^2$$ and $$4x^2+20x+25=(2x+5)^2$$

Comment: This seems very nice solution but I could not understand your very first step. are you using any formula here?

Comment: i use $$\log_a b=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$$

Comment: that brings everything in terms of $ln$ and gets rid of all different bases. beautiful!

Comment: thank you!! you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that

$$
10x^2 +29x+10= (5x+2)(2x+5)
$$

and
$$
4x^2 +20x+25=(2x+5)^2
$$

and remember that $$log_a b=\frac{1}{\log_b a}$$